# Как по-человечески изменить язык в android приложении?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я проанализировал около 4-5 вопросов на стэке по поводу того как можно изменить язык в android приложении. В некоторых писались костыли, при которых нужно код проверки локали тянуть в каждую активити,в некоторых вообще всё отваливалось на андроиде 9-10.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать как реально можно сменить язык и на лету и с перезагрузкой? Не верится что всё так костыльно
При этом не проверяя в каждой активити локаль после перезагрузки/смены языка,если это возможно. Буду признателен

Comment: Простого решения нет. Часть проблем решается использованием только одной активистки в приложении.

Comment: Пока что делаю проект с несколькими активити. Вот тут новый комментарий к посту 2020 года https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Не очень понял что я должен был по ссылке увидеть) Если у вас несколько активити - надо ещё и пересоздавать активити в стеке, возвращаясь к ним. Вроде бы в `onRestart` методе, как описано в одном ответе по ссылке. Также надо иметь в виду, что работать это всё будет только для APK файлов или надо AppBundle собирать сразу со всеми локалями - иначе краш будет в рантайме из-за отсутствующих ресурсов

Comment: кошмар какой-то. И что, только в приложениях с одной активностью со сменой языка не будет проблем?

Comment: Проблемы будут если проблемно реализовать. Если сделать нормально - нормально будет) С несколькими активити просто чуть больше кода надо написать. На самом деле задача не очень сложная

Comment: Ну в активити настроек если меняется язык,то нужно в onRestart в каждой активити проверять текущий установленный язык, правильно?

Comment: Ага, вроде верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полное название библиотеки - zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android
https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android

- данная библиотека помогает решить проблему.
  Вы либо наследуетесь от библиотечного класса вашим классом App и базовым классом активности/фрагмента и просто применяете

```
updateLocale(Locales.Turkish)
```

Либо если не хотите этого делать,то просто внедряете методы библиотечные в свой код и делаете то же самое.
Второй вариант решения проблемы с переключением языков - делать SingleActivity приложения